# Latex: reference subfigures did not appeared inside text

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am working on a publication for IEEE and trying to add 3 figures as subfigure in latex on top over 2 column text.

I have tried the folloeing latex code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
    \centering
    \label{fig_path_loss}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{Find3.jpg}} 
    \label{fig_rain}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{Find2.jpg}} 
    \
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{Find1.jpg}}
    \label{fig_gas}
    \caption{(a) aaa (b) bbb (c) ccc }
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that Overleaf I use didnt reference the subfigures.

```
(subcaption)                with the subfigure package.

See the subcaption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.66 \subcaption@CheckCompatibility
                                   
If you do not understand this error, please take a closer look
at the documentation of the `subcaption' package, especially the
section about errors.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

I added `\usepackage{subcaption}` on the beginning of my doc.

Could you please suggest me a solution of this issue?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0):

- you are missing the `graphicx` package
- labels need to be placed in or after the caption
- the subcaption package automatically loads the caption package. In principle you don't need to load the caption package yourself, but if you absolutely want to load it, do it before the subcaption package
- you can use the `\subcaptionbox` macro from the subcaption package like this:

---

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig_rain}}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck}} 
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck}} 
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig_gas}}{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{(a) aaa (b) bbb (c) ccc }
    \label{fig_path_loss}
\end{figure*}

\subref{fig_gas}

\ref{fig_gas}

\end{document}
```